# How to call a function with different values without recreating an new arrow function on every render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

It's clear and we all know that using arrow functions in the `render` method of a class component isn't good because it creates new functions on every render.

e.g.

```
render() { 
    return (
        <div onClick={() => console.log('this is bad')}>I'm dangerous</div>
    )
}
```

But in my case, what I what to do is have a function (`foo`) that receives a parameter and set the state with that parameter. And I have multiple elements, each one with a different value for calling `foo`.

e.g.

```
foo = value => this.setState({value})

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => this.foo(1)}>1</div> //  this is also bad
            <div onClick={() => this.foo(2)}>2</div> //  this is also bad
            <div onClick={() => this.foo(3)}>3</div> //  this is also bad
            <div onClick={() => this.foo(4)}>4</div> //  this is also bad
            <div onClick={() => this.foo(5)}>5</div> //  this is also bad
        </div>
    )
}
```

So I need a walkaround on this, I need to call the same function only passing different arguments.

What I try to come up with is

1. Creating a function that returns a function

   ```
   foo = value => () => this.setState({value})

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <div onClick={this.foo(1)}>1</div> 
               <div onClick={this.foo(2)}>2</div> 
               <div onClick={this.foo(3)}>3</div> 
               <div onClick={this.foo(4)}>4</div> 
               <div onClick={this.foo(5)}>5</div> 
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```

   But I think this is just as bad as the first example
2. Creating on function for each value

   ```
   foo1 = value => this.setState({value})
   foo2 = value => this.setState({value})
   foo3 = value => this.setState({value})
   foo4 = value => this.setState({value})
   foo5 = value => this.setState({value})

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <div onClick={this.foo1}>1</div>
               <div onClick={this.foo2}>2</div>
               <div onClick={this.foo2}>3</div>
               <div onClick={this.foo4}>4</div>
               <div onClick={this.foo5}>5</div>
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```

This isn't bad in the case where you create a new function on every render, but this way, my component just becomes huge and very bad.

Giving this situation, How can I make this function or rendering without creating new functions on every render and don't create one function for each element value?

Just keep in mind that the real values in my case aren't numeric numbers (1234), the element of the `onClick` isn't a simple `div` element and `foo` doesn't only call `this.setState`, but do other stuff too. it's just an example.

Comment: you can add a `data-attribute` to your divs, then use the `event.target` passed into your function by `onClick` to get the data from the attribute. This way, only one function is needed, at it can be a reference (so it won't be created each render)

Comment: @NickParsons That makes sense and it's a very good idea

Comment: Why the down vote? What is wrong? I made a very clear question, with examples and everything.

Comment: I always use your 1. solution. I do not see why it is bad. You create a class field with an arrow function, it will created only once. Then you use it from multiple places.

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs the first example is just a contextualization for the question

Comment: @Vencovsky Ok, but what is the problem with it? I think that is the correct solution.

Comment: why would your example #1 be bad? your example #2 is horrible, yes, but i don't see any issues with #1.

Comment: @MarkusDresch because it creates a new arrow function on every render

Comment: no it doesn't... `<div onClick={this.foo(4)}>4</div>` only calls a function on click.

Comment: @MarkusDresch `onClick={this.foo(4)}` calls `foo` on every render and `foo` creates and return a new function. Which means, it creates a new function on every render.

Comment: you would have to bind `this` though, since it's not an arrow function: `<div onClick={this.foo.bind(this, 4)}>4</div>`

Comment: @MarkusDresch `foo = value => () => this.setState({value})` is an arrow function that returns another arrow function. No need for bind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207425/discussion-between-vencovsky-and-markus-dresch).

Comment: ah yes, you're right, i see. you could just use a normal function with bind then if you are worried about arrow functions. sounds a lot like premature optimization though.

Comment: @MarkusDresch [why you shouldn't use `.bind`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#no-bind-or-arrow-functions-in-jsx-props-reactjsx-no-bind) `A bind call or arrow function in a JSX prop will create a brand new function on every single render. This is bad for performance, as it may cause unnecessary re-renders if a brand new function is passed as a prop to a component that uses reference equality check on the prop to determine if it should update.`

Comment: @MarkusDresch using `.bind` or arrow function will get the same performance issue

Answer (score 2):

The way you solve this in class-based components is to bind the function when the class itself is created.

```
class C {
  foo = () => {
    this.setState({...})
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.foo} />
  }
}
```

This will ensure that there is only one instance of that function per instance of the class. I would only recommend doing this if you have demonstrated there is a performance concern with having functions created in each render call.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Doesn't explain how to deal with multiple values for the same function. Please take a look at the examples I made and what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Ah, my mistake. In that case there is no work around without adding an attribute to each element, as your self-answer proposes. Why do you want to do this? Have you demonstrated there is an issue with creating a function each render? [They really are not that expensive.](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods)

*Another* alternative would be to convert your function to a function component and use [React.useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) which would be my preferred approach

Comment: Do I need to explain why I want to do something to get an answer of how to do something? But if you really want to know, it's because I'm refactoring a project where the past developer made a bunch of functions for a bunch of buttons that do the same thing, but only with a different value. If it was a isolated case, it would be ok, but it's all over the project.

Comment: Converting it to a functional component would be great too!

Comment: I only ask because I'm not in the habit of encouraging people to prematurely optimize, which is what this question read like to begin with :)

Comment: I completely agree with Dan. I always write code to promote readability.

Answer (score 0):

I could add a `data-attribute` to the `div`, then use the `event.target` inside the `onClick` as  Nick Parsons said, and based on his comment I came with another solution that maybe it's better.

I could create an component that receives a `value` and a `onClick` prop and inside the component I would just call `this.prop.onClick(this.props.value)`. this way I would pass only one function to each component.

It's like `data-attribute` but with different props.